# Autowiring only certain arguments of a constructor

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Is it possible in Spring to autowire only specific arguments of a constructor?

I defined:

```
<bean class="MyClass">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="object name" />
</bean>
```

With:

```
public class MyClass{
    private String name;
    private MyDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(String name, MyDao dao){
        // assign...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I'd like `MyDao` object to be autowired, while explicitly define `name` argument.
Is it possible?

Defining a bean using XML requires to manually define all arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that with the autowired constructor, because it affects all parameters, but you can do this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO dao;

    public MyClass(String name){
        // assign only name
    }

    // ...
}
```

It is similar to having a setter for the DAO but you don't expose that public setter it in your class.

Comment: ok, so I have to change my contructor... or use an explicit reference in my XML definition...

Comment: Yes, that would depend on the rest of your project, if it uses autowiring for most bean references, or explicit definition in the XML, to mantain consistency.

Comment: But isn't Field Injection not recommended? How should we go about when a client need to call this autowired constructor with few specific arguments?

Comment: @GopalSAkshintala you could try setter injection.  In the above example, you would create a method called `setDao()` and annotate it with @Autowired.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you are asking if you can wire in a MyDao instance that you have defined elsewhere in your context, and provide a hard-coded string value for the name parameter.  If that is correct, you would configure your class like

```
<bean class="MyClass">
  <constructor-arg value="Hardcoded string value for the name" />
  <constructor-arg ref="myDaoInstance" />
</bean>
```

And elsewhere in your context file

```
<bean class="MyDao" id="myDaoInstance>
  //relevant config
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should add @Autowired to the MyDao dao; declaration, then change your constructor to just take the name param. You will automatically be able to access MyDao

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Java Config.

```java
@Bean
public MyClass myClass(MyDao dao) {
  return new MyClass("tst", dao);
}
```